# Java OKhttp Authentication Exception: failed to to authenticate with proxy

Tags: java, api, retrofit, okhttp

**Question:** How do I add a authorization proxy to OkHTTP.

I have a using a proxy with ip:port:username:password, although when i run my program i get an error saying `INFO: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on https://www.footlocker.nl/...` I used the Authentication method with `Credentials.basic()` but  `finalobject.getusername` and `finalobject.getpassword()` return the full proxy (ip:port:username:password) instead of just the username and password. My Credentials are returning  a
Basic credentialresponse like:  `Credentials Info: Basic dXNlci1tcGgwMV9GNVdyWC1jb3VudHJ5LW5sLXNlc3Npb23tRjhBRE5BYmc7UmFnZTFqS1ZyVGlGQTU=`.

Also, `proxyRandom` contains an Arraylist of proxyObjects.

See image for more info:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L728Y.png)

Here is the code:

```
public Footlockerv1(String base, String keywords, String size, Billing.ProfileObject profile,
                        ArrayList<ProxyObjects.ProxyObject> proxyRandom) {
        super();

        ProxyObjects.ProxyObject object = null;
        for (ProxyObjects.ProxyObject b : proxyRandom) {
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(proxyRandom.size());
            System.out.println("Random Proxies: " + proxyRandom.get(index));
            b = proxyRandom.get(index);
            object = new ProxyObjects.ProxyObject(b.getAddress(), b.getPort(), b.getUsername(), b.getPassword());

        }

        System.out.println("Full Proxy name: " + object +
                "\nConstructed Proxy Name "
                + "Addres: " + object.getAddress() + ". "
                + "Port: " + object.getPort() + ". "
                + "Username: " + object.getUsername() + ". "
                + "Password: " + object.getPassword());

        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        final HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptorv2 = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptorv2.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        InetSocketAddress proxyAddr = new InetSocketAddress(object.getAddress(), object.getPort());
        java.net.Proxy proxyy = new java.net.Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxyAddr);

        System.out.println("\n Used proxy: " + proxyy);

        ProxyObjects.ProxyObject finalObject;
        finalObject = object;
        System.out.println("Final object: " + finalObject);



        Authenticator proxyAuthenticatorr = (route, response) -> {
            String credentialTest = Credentials.basic(finalObject.getUsername(), finalObject.getPassword());

            System.out.println("Credentials Info: " + credentialTest + " . Info are:  " + finalObject.getUsername() + " " +
                    " & " + finalObject.getPassword());

            System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", finalObject.getUsername());
            System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", finalObject.getPassword());
            System.setProperty("jdk.https.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes", "");
            return response.request().newBuilder()
                    .header("Proxy-Authorization", credentialTest)
                    .build();
        };

        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .proxy(proxyy)
                .proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticatorr)
//                .authenticator(proxyAuthenticatorr)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .cookieJar(new SessionCookieJar())
                .addInterceptor(chain ->
                {
                    Request request = chain.request();

                    Request.Builder newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                            .header("Accept", "*/*")
                            .method("GET", null)
                            .header("DNT", String.valueOf(1))
                            .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
                            .header("User-Agent", RandomUserAgent.getRandomUserAgent()
                            );

                    System.out.println("Request: " + request);
                    return chain.proceed(newRequest.build());

                }).addInterceptor(interceptorv2)
                .build();

        final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(base)
                .client(client)
                .build();

        api = retrofit.create(API_Retrofit.class);

        this.proxy = proxyRandom;
        this.base = base;
        this.keywords = keywords;
        this.size = size;
        this.profile = profile;
        debug = true;
    }
```